# How to test an EventEmitter from service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am new in Angular/Jasmine and need help to test a little peace of code.

My ts file `createcustomer.ts`
My method shoots a boolean event that is listened in another component. I need test if the event below was emitted

```
export class CreateCustomerComponent {
  constructor(public breadCrumbService: BreadCrumbService) { }
  emit() {
    this.breadCrumbService.createCustomer$.emit(false)
  }
}
```

`createcustomer.spec.ts`
I wanna test my method above

```
emit() {
  this.breadCrumbService.createCustomer$.emit(false)
}
```

My test pass and I know how to test a simple emit in component, but an emit of a service I do know yet.

```
describe('CreateCustomerComponent ', () => {
  let component: CreateCustomerComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreateCustomerComponent >;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ],
      declarations: [
        createCustomerComponent
      ],
      schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: BreadCrumbService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateBotComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create the component CreateCustomerComponent ', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I expect createCustomer$ haveBeenCalledWith(false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe('CreateCustomerComponent ', () => {
  let component: CreateCustomerComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreateCustomerComponent >;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ...
      providers: [
        {
          provide: BreadCrumbService,
          // use can describe structure of mocked object with useValue or use declare mock class and bind it with useClass
          useValue: { createCustomer$: { emit: jasmine.createSpy('emit') } }
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  ...
  // what method do we test
  describe('.emit()', () => {
    // expected  behaviors
    it('should emit false via createCustomer$ from breadCrumbService', inject([BreadCrumbService], (service: BreadCrumbService) => {
      component.emit();// or you can play around and try to trigger it via template interactions
      expect(service.createCustomer$.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
    }));
  });
```